# Authentication Popup Happening Inside network

Tags: selenium, authentication, iis, selenium-chromedriver, windows-authentication

I am working on some browser tests in selenium on Chrome. I have a script which ran on my personal machine can connect to a site and has no issues. However when the script is ran on a machine inside our network, it pops an authentication pop up. When I click cancel on the authentication box, it continues to a user login page which allows regular authentication.  I have disabled IWA for the browser but it is still popping up.

I tried passing username@password:url but that did not work. Our test account is not connected to the domain and this website will try to use your Windows account but outside the network it defaults to the login page where we do have regular userid/pw for certain people (like our test account they created for us). We do not control the server so I cannot change that behavior.

I would normally close the alert in this case however selenium is not recognizing the authentication popup as an alert so the script just hangs.  So step 2 would be the userid/password sent in the URL but that doesn't work either.  I would prefer not to go the route of installing any other tools (like AutoIt) and try to solve this with settings.

Is there a way to skip the authentication popup in chrome?  In the header the response is its using "Negotiate" for auth. I do not get that when testing on my local machine outside the network.

Comment: Did you try username@password:url or usename:password@url? Because second one is correct

Comment: I did username:password@url.  That was a typo by me